# The result of an xpath is {{price}} in Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

When I try to scrape price list the value that exists is a variable. You could help me with this please.

This is the source code:

```
<div id="template-precio" type="text/x-handlebars-template" style="display:none">

{{#if potentialSavedPrice}}
    <span class="saving">Ahorra <b>${{potentialSavedPrice}}</b></span>
    <span class="list">Precio lista: <i>${{price}}</i></span>
    <span class="lable">Precio web:</span>
    {{#if eCoupon}}
        <span class="price">${{potentialCouponPrice}}</span>
        <span class="coupon">Usa el cupón <b>{{eCoupon}}</b></span>
    {{else}}
        <span class="price">${{potentialDiscountedPrice}}</span>
    {{/if}}
{{else}}
    <span class="lable">Precio web:</span>
    <span class="price">${{price}}</span>
{{/if}}
```

My xpath:

> response.xpath('.//*[@class="list"]/i/text()').extract_first()

Result:

`'${{price}}'`

This is the code in the chrome inspector:

```
<div class="details-price">
            <div class="">


    <span class="saving">Ahorra <b>$369.943,87</b></span>
    <span class="list">Precio lista: <i>$3.699.438,68</i></span>
    <span class="lable">Precio web:</span>

        <span class="price">$3.329.494,81</span>
        <span class="coupon">Usa el cupón <b>B2BUSINESS</b></span>
```

This is the page:
http://www3.lenovo.com/co/es/ofertas-y-cupones
Thank you

Comment: That variable is probably being filled by some templating engine or JavaScript, right? Can't really tell until you give us website URL so we can check.

Comment: In cases like this you have to disable javascript and look around for these variables in page source. It's also possible that those variables are delivered via AJAX request.

Comment: Look at the source html and see if you can search for the value you are looking for?

Comment: In the question add the link of the page. The page is built in Java according to builtwith.com. It's crazy because when I use scrapy it gives me this result '${{price}}' . Thanks for the help

Comment: There are multiple elements on that page with a `@class` value of `list`, including an element in a handlebars template. What's probably happening is that you're getting the value from the template because that's the first `@class = 'list'` in the page. You need an XPath that more specifically targets the element you want.

Comment: Thank you @JLRishe Apparently I have to work it as json